# Not able to browse internet through WiFi in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: wireless, iwlwifi

I am able to connect to WiFi but not able to browse internet on Ubuntu 14.04. It was working fine earlier.

ifconfig as given below:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 3c:97:0e:55:74:a7  
          inet6 addr: fe80::3e97:eff:fe55:74a7/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:9000  Metric:1
          RX packets:15017 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:6709 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:5679208 (5.6 MB)  TX bytes:1147562 (1.1 MB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:137 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:137 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:9745 (9.7 KB)  TX bytes:9745 (9.7 KB)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 20:16:d8:1f:e5:5f  
          inet addr:192.168.137.51  Bcast:192.168.137.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::2216:d8ff:fe1f:e55f/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:60 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1761 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:6977 (6.9 KB)  TX bytes:197694 (197.6 KB)
```

Out put of  route -n

```
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.137.1   0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 wlan0
192.168.137.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     9      0        0 wlan0
```

output of ping -c 4 google.com
Nothings comes

```
ping -c 4 8.8.8.8
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 192.168.137.43 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.137.43 icmp_seq=2 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.137.43 icmp_seq=3 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.137.43 icmp_seq=4 Destination Host Unreachable




06:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8188CE 802.11b/g/n WiFi Adapter [10ec:8176] (rev 01)
Subsystem: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device [10ec:8195]
Kernel driver in use: rtl8192ce
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `route -n` terminal command

Comment: Please also add the output of the following commands: `ping -c 4 google.com` and `ping -c 4 8.8.8.8`

Comment: Thanks for your response. 
route -n

Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.137.1   0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 wlan0
192.168.137.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     9      0        0 wlan0

ping -c 4 google.com

ping -c 4 8.8.8.8
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 192.168.137.43 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.137.43 icmp_seq=2 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.137.43 icmp_seq=3 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.137.43 icmp_seq=4 Destination Host Unreachable

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` terminal command.

Answer (score 0):

I think you've a gateway issue, to be certain run the command `traceroute 8.8.8.8` - the first hop should be the gateway. `sudo apt-get install traceroute` to install traceroute. Please post the outcome.

You wrote 'It was working fine earlier', so either you changed the gateway or you adjusted settings in `/etc/networking/interface`. Please post your interface setup. (See example below in post)

If you're able to ping 8.8.8.8 but not google.com you might also have a DNS issue then,

resolvconf generated `/etc/resolv.conf`,

```
# Generated by resolvconf
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
```

If you updated `/etc/resolv.conf` restart it by `systemctl restart networking`
 or `sudo service networking restart`

Check if you've the correct nameserver, you can also reinstall resolvconf and see if that resolves it.
`sudo apt-get remove --purge resolvconf && sudo apt-get install --reinstall resolvconf`

Another place where DNS is configured is in `/etc/network/interfaces`, if you configured it static.

example `/etc/network/interface`:

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
    address 192.168.1.2
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    gateway 192.168.1.1
    dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4
```

Comment: @NaveenGupta - what was the issue if I may ask? :)

Comment: After running below command it was working fine. the issue was with resolvconf :

sudo apt-get remove --purge resolvconf && sudo apt-get install --reinstall resolvconf

Comment: @NaveenGupta - cool! Glad to be able to help :)